# Pandas: concat dataframes and summ value in columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes and I need to concat it

df1

```
ac                Hi-Tech Безопасность  Hi-Tech Интернет  Hi-Tech Компьютеры
g0erl94ixwwzetju  0                     3313              8
g0f6b7yuyj9vctww  0                     0                 0
g0ibu3bokld1ea9e  0                     12,5              61
```

df2

```
ac                Hi-Tech Безопасность  Hi-Tech Интернет  Hi-Tech  Интерфейс
g0erl94ixwwzetju  0                     3,666666667       0
g0f6b7yuyj9vctww  0                     0                 0
g0ibu3bokld1ea9e  0                     8,5               0
```

Desire output

```
ac                Hi-Tech Безопасность  Hi-Tech Интернет  Hi-Tech Интерфейс  Hi-Tech Компьютеры
g0erl94ixwwzetju  0                     3316,666666667    0                  8
g0f6b7yuyj9vctww  0                     0                 0                  0
g0ibu3bokld1ea9e  0                     21                0                  61
```

I have tried

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ac')
```

But it returns dataframe with value from first dataframe, not summ.
How can I fix that?

Comment: `df_out = df1 + df2`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it returns me dataframe with empty cells

Comment: Are all your columns floats or are they strings? Especially the 3316,666....

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ all are float or int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with parameter `fill_value=0`, but first `replace` `,` to `.` and cast to `float`s:

```
df11 = df1.set_index('ac').replace(',','.', regex=True).astype(float)
df22 = df2.set_index('ac').replace(',','.', regex=True).astype(float)
df = df11.add(df22, fill_value=0).fillna(0).reset_index()
print (df)
                 ac  Hi-Tech  Hi-Tech Безопасность  Hi-Tech Интернет  \
0  g0erl94ixwwzetju      0.0                   0.0       3316.666667   
1  g0f6b7yuyj9vctww      0.0                   0.0          0.000000   
2  g0ibu3bokld1ea9e      0.0                   0.0         21.000000   

   Hi-Tech Компьютеры  Интерфейс  
0                 8.0        0.0  
1                 0.0        0.0  
2                61.0        0.0
```

Another solution is use parameter `decimal=','` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) instead `replace` and `astype`.

Comment: It union dataframes, but not sum. I have all columns twice.

Comment: I think there is problem with `,` instead `.` for floats. So need replace first

Comment: It's strange. In real data there are 72 columns in df1 and 114 columns in df2. But in result df I have 184. Can you see my dataframes, if I send it you to email?

Comment: It is up to you. But I think missing 2 columns -  maybe `ac`, because it is index

Comment: So after reset_index I think len of output columns is 72 + 114 - 1 (ac in df1 and ac in df2 create  one ac in output)

Comment: 184 columns( See in email, please

Comment: sure, give me a some time

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my fault. In some columns were 2 whitespaces